# Button image will not change

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uibutton

I am practising / learning swift and am making a tic tac toe game. I have fiddled around trying to get a button image to change however nothing changes when the button is clicked.

Am i correct to be applying this action to the sender in the click event handler? If so, why might this not be working?

Thanks

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var playerOneTurn = true;
    let cross = UIImage(named: "Cross") as UIImage;
    let naught = UIImage(named: "naught") as UIImage;

    @IBAction func topLeftBtn(sender: UIButton) {

        var image = sender.imageForState(UIControlState.Normal);

        if(image == nil){
            if(playerOneTurn == true){
                sender.setImage(naught,forState: UIControlState.Highlighted);
                playerOneTurn = false;
            }else{
               sender.setImage(cross,forState: UIControlState.Highlighted);
                playerOneTurn = true;
            }
        }
        checkForWinner();

    }
```

Comment: Did you get this sorted out? Please consider accepting/upvoting answers that are helpful to you. It is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're setting only the `Highlighted` button state image when the button is pressed. Is that what you wanted to do? Try the below instead:

```
    if(image == nil){
        if(playerOneTurn == true){
            sender.setImage(naught,forState: UIControlState.Normal);
            playerOneTurn = false;
        }else{
           sender.setImage(cross,forState: UIControlState.Normal);
            playerOneTurn = true;
        }
    }
```